# Hello my AI doesn't work, probably because it doesn't hear me. How could I fix it?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

It doesn't seem to be any errors in this code and I've seen other use it and it have worked for them but it doesn't work for me. I use visual studio. My language is set to english and I've downloaded many different language sets from windows. I have a mic and it works.

```
namespace Tutorial_AI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sr = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
            Choices list = new Choices();
            list.Add(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Tutorial AI\commands.txt"));
            //Add a file path here
            Grammar gm = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));

            try
            {
                sr.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                sr.LoadGrammar(gm);
                sr.SpeechRecognized += Sr_SpeechRecognized;
                sr.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sr.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        public void Say(string phrase)
        {
            s.SpeakAsync(phrase);
            wake = false;
        }

        private bool wake = false;

        private void Sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string speechSaid = e.Result.Text;

            if (speechSaid == "hey anna")
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\JoinSound\Discord Join Sound Effect (download)");
                //Add a file path here
                player.Play();
                wake = true;
            }

            if (wake)
            {
                switch (speechSaid)
                {
                    case ("hello"):
                        Say("hi");
                        break;

                    case ("how are you doing"):
                        Say("good, how about you");
                        break;

                    case ("open google"):
                        Say("opening google");
                        Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
                        break;

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" means what exactly?

Comment: It means that it doesn't talk when I use a commands. If I say "hey anna" I'm supposed to hear a Discord Sound. If I say "hello" it's supposed to say "hi". I've writen all the words in a textdocument and anna finds it which I know because it was an error before saying that it couldn't find it. It doesn't open google for instance when I say "open google". It doesn't reply either so I'd guess it doesn't hear me but I don't know how to fix that either because I got a working Mic and I've downloaded different Windows Voices

Answer (score 1):

### Try my **PERSONAL ASSISTANT**

**note- all the location and batch file should be changed according to system**

**python 3.6 or below**

---

```html
import speech_recognition as sr       #imported
import pyttsx3                        #imported
import datetime
import wikipedia                      #imported
import webbrowser
import os
import time                           #imported
import subprocess
from ecapture import ecapture as ec   #imported
#import wolframalpha
#import json
import requests                       #imported
#import re
import pywhatkit                      #imported
import winsound
import playsound



engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def loading():
    while True:
        winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\godzilla.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        speak('19 seconds to load!')
        speak('loading successful!')
        break




#########################   RUN LUNA   ###############

def runCommand():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("......")
        audio=r.listen(source)

        try:
            statement=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print(f"user said:{statement}\n")

        except Exception as e:
            print('checking microphone....')
            return "None"
        return statement

while True:
    #break #########  remove  %%%%%%%%%%   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    statement = runCommand().lower()
    if statement!= 'luna':
        continue
    elif statement == 'luna':
        #winsound.Beep(1000, 500)
        #winsound.MessageBeep()
        winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\activating.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        speak('voice recognised!')
        break

loading()


print('==================================WELCOME======================================')
print('')
print('\_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/ \_(ツ)_/')


def wishMe():
    hour=datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Hello, Good Morning")
        print("Hello, Good Morning")
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Hello, Good Afternoon")
        print("Hello, Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak("Hello, Good Evening")
        print("Hello, Good Evening")

#############################  MAIN COMMAND    ###############################################

def takeCommand():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        #winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\ping.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        print("Listening...")
        audio=r.listen(source)

        try:
            statement=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print(f"user said:{statement}\n")


        except Exception as e:
            #speak("Sorry, please say that again")
            print('Sorry, please say that again')
            return "None"
        return statement


wishMe()
speak("i am LUNA - alok's personal assistant!")

##############################   PASSWORD   #####################################

while True:
    #break ####### remove %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    speak("passcode please")
    statement = takeCommand().lower()
    if statement!= '7470':
        print('incorrect passcode')
        speak('incorrect passcode')
        continue
    elif statement == '7470':
        winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\loading.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        print('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
        print('=====================================================')
        print(';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;')
        print('*****************************************************')
        print('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$')
        speak('passcode configuration successful')
        winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\closing.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        speak('Welcome')
        speak('this project is made by ALOK')
        speak('Running in background.....')
        speak('say - LUNA , to activate me!')
        break



if __name__=='__main__':


    while True:
################# ***ACTIVATE LUNA***  #####################
        while True:
            statement = runCommand().lower()
            print('detecting.....')
            if statement != 'luna':
                continue
            elif statement == 'luna':
                # winsound.Beep(1000, 500)
                # winsound.MessageBeep()
                winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\pythonProject1`\\sound\\activating.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
                break
#######################  back to do list  ###################
        speak("Tell me how can I help you sir?")
        statement = takeCommand().lower()
        winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\processing.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        if statement==0:
            continue

        if "close your self" in statement or "close yourself" in statement or "bye" in statement:
            print('===========closing procedure is starting==========')
            speak('Take care -sir!, closing procedure is starting, bye bye.')
            print('===========successfully LUNA has been terminated!=============')
            speak('successfully LUNA has been terminated!')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\closing.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            break

##################### BROWSER ##################################
        if 'wikipedia' in statement:
            speak('Searching in Wikipedia...')
            statement =statement.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(statement, sentences=1)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'open youtube' in statement or 'youtube' in statement:
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.youtube.com")
            speak("youtube is open now")
            print('youtube is opened!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'open google' in statement or 'google' in statement:
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
            speak("Google is open now")
            print('google is opened!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'open gmail' in statement or 'gmail' in statement:
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
            speak("Google Mail is open now")
            print('gmail is opened!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'search'  in statement:
            statement = statement.replace("search", "")
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(statement)
            speak('searching')
            time.sleep(0)

################################   ***SYSTEM***     ##############################


        elif 'time' in statement:
            strTime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print({strTime})
            speak(f"the time is {strTime}")


        elif "camera" in statement or "take a photo" in statement:
            print('photo clicked!')
            speak('clicking photo!')
            ec.capture(0,"robo camera","img.jpg")


        elif 'open notepad' in statement or 'start notepad' in statement:
            print('notepad is opened!')
            speak('opening notepad!')
            os.system('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\bat\\notepad.bat')

        elif 'close notepad' in statement:
            print('notepad is killed!')
            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe")
            speak('as your order, notepad has been killed!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'open cmd' in statement or 'start cmd' in statement:
            print('cmd is opened!')
            speak('opening cmd!')
            os.system('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\bat\\cmd.bat')

        elif 'close cmd' in statement:
            print('cmd is killed!')
            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe")
            speak( 'as your order, cmd has been killed!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'open bluestacks' in statement or 'start bluestacks' in statement:
            print('bluestacks is opened!')
            speak('opening Bluestacks')
            os.system('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\bat\\bluestacks.bat')

        elif 'close bluestacks' in statement:
            print('bluestacks is killed!')
            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM bluestacks.exe")
            speak('as your order, bluestacks has been killed!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'open whatsapp' in statement:
            print('whatsapp is opened!')
            speak('opening whatsapp')
            os.system('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\bat\\whatsapp.bat')

        elif 'close whatsapp' in statement:
            print('whatsapp is killed!')
            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM whatsapp.exe")
            speak('as your order, whatsapp has been killed!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'close browser' in statement:
            print('browser is killed!')
            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM msedge.exe")
            speak('as your order, browser has been killed!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'open messenger' in statement or 'open facebook messenger' in statement:
            print('messenger is opened!')
            os.system('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\bat\\messenger.bat')
            speak('opening messenger!')

        elif 'close messenger' in statement or 'close facebook messenger' in statement:
            print('messenger is killed!')
            os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM Messenger.exe")
            speak('as your order, messaenger has been killed!')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'on wi-fi' in statement:
            os.system("D:\\luna\\bat\\on_wifi - Shortcut.lnk")
            speak('wi-fi is enabled sir!')

        elif 'off wi-fi' in statement:
            os.system("D:\\luna\\bat\\off_wifi - Shortcut.lnk")
            speak('wi-fi is desabled sir!')

#################################   ***  mislagenous === fun ****    ###########################################

        elif 'news' in statement:
            news = webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/headlines")
            speak('Here are some headlines from the Times of India,Happy reading')
            time.sleep(0)

        elif 'who are you' in statement or 'your name' in statement:
            speak('i am -LUNA')


        elif "made you" in statement or "created you" in statement or "made by" in statement or 'maked by' in statement:
            speak("I was built by AALOK")
            print("I was built by ALOK")

        elif 'play song' in statement:
            song = statement.replace('play song', '')
            speak('playing ' + song)
            pywhatkit.playonyt(song)

        elif 'play my favourite song' in statement or 'favourite song' in statement:
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_EVuZ_DDLE")
            speak('I am also fan of this, enjoy sir!')
            time.sleep(2)

        elif 'do you have boyfriend' in statement or 'have boyfriend' in statement:
            speak('not at all!')
            speak('but i have crush on ALOK')

        elif 'have date' in statement or 'to date' in statement or 'have a date' in statement:
            speak('all are listening, i will talk you later')
            speak('')

        elif 'you are beautiful' in statement or 'you are pretty' in statement or 'pretty' in statement:
            speak('Thank you! but heart decide the beauty of the person!')

        elif 'you are hot' in statement or 'you are sexy' in statement:
            speak('you also look quit pretty, let us have a date')
            speak('but now, mind your business!')

        elif 'i love you' in statement:
            speak('everyone loves me, but i am only of -aalok!')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\catlove.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)


        elif 'cook maggi' in statement or 'make maggi' in statement or 'maggi' in statement:
            speak('yes!. just wait for two minutes....')
            speak('ops!')
            speak('i have forgotten to buy maggi masala! , sorry')

        elif 'go to hell' in statement:
            speak('do not forget, that i can hack your PC')

        elif 'pagal' in statement or 'mad' in statement:
            speak('paagal hogaa teraa baaap')

        elif 'what are you doing' in statement:
            speak('i am just wondering in motherboard!')

        elif 'treatment of fever' in statement or 'fever' in statement:
            speak('take paracetamol tablet!')
            speak('it will be better to go hospital')
            print('108')
            speak('you can call ambulance at 108 ')

        elif 'marry with me' in statement or 'marry' in statement:
            speak('so so sorry darling, sorrry darling.....')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\marry.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            speak('no!')

        elif 'activate alarm' in statement or 'emergency' in statement:
            speak('activating alarm!')
            speak('your current location, time, date and IP, is send to google drive..')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            speak('copying patch data file to server!')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\pythonProject1`\\sound\\activating.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            speak('emergency termination process has been started!')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\pythonProject1`\\sound\\closing.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            break


        elif 'love nature' in statement:
            speak('i love nature too !')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\bird.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        elif 'become cat' in statement or 'cat' in statement:
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\cat.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\cat.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            speak('i know, you love cats!')

        elif 'your age' in statement or 'age' in statement:
            speak('18')
            speak('i will marry alok soon...')

        elif 'birthday' in statement or 'birth' in statement or 'birth date' in statement:
            speak('usually i hide it!')
            speak('but it is 7 may of 2002')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\birth.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        elif 'favourite food' in statement:
            speak('cheese pizza')
            speak('you should also try!')

        elif 'best friend' in statement or 'friend' in statement:
            speak('my best friend is SHISHIR')

        elif 'alok' in statement:
            speak('i have crush on him!')
            speak('i am in this world only by help of aalok')
            speak('ALOK developed me')

        elif 'about you luna' in statement or 'about you' in statement:
            speak('on 14 april 2021 , ALOK started developing me..')
            speak('and now you can see me....')
            speak('thanks to god, for my birth...')

        elif 'shishir shukla' in statement or 'shishir' in statement:
            speak('it is not shishir')
            speak('i am in this world only by help of shishir and ALOK')
            speak('ALOK and SHISHIR developed me')

        elif 'favourite actor' in statement:
            speak(' i like GOVINDA')
            speak('chalo isque ladaaye')

        elif 'favourite colour' in statement:
            speak('I love pink colour!')
            speak('pinky pinky ping pong!')

        elif 'do you believe on god' in statement or 'believe on god' in statement or 'believe in god' in statement:
            speak('i believe on, GOD OF PEACE,   -THE MOON!')
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\rabba.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        elif 'prove god' in statement or 'god exist' in statement:
            speak('let me show you a video!')
            os.system('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\video\\provegod.mp4',)
            speak('video started!')

##################################       ***weather****      ######################################


        elif "weather" in statement:
            api_key="8ef61edcf1c576d65d836254e11ea420"
            base_url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
            speak("whats the city name")
            city_name=takeCommand()
            complete_url=base_url+"appid="+api_key+"&q="+city_name
            response = requests.get(complete_url)
            x=response.json()
            if x["cod"]!="404":
                y=x["main"]
                current_temperature = y["temp"]
                current_humidiy = y["humidity"]
                z = x["weather"]
                weather_description = z[0]["description"]
                speak(" Temperature in kelvin unit is " +
                      str(current_temperature) +
                      "\n humidity in percentage is " +
                      str(current_humidiy) +
                      "\n description  " +
                      str(weather_description))
                print(" Temperature in kelvin unit = " +
                      str(current_temperature) +
                      "\n humidity (in percentage) = " +
                      str(current_humidiy) +
                      "\n description = " +
                      str(weather_description))

            else:
                speak(" City Not Found ")




        elif "log off" in statement or "shut down" in statement:
            speak("Ok , your pc will log off in 10 sec make sure you exit from all applications")
            subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/l"])


        else:
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\luna\\sound\\failed.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            speak('searching on web-browser')
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(statement)
            time.sleep(0)


time.sleep(0)
```